# Maven Conditional Statement

Tags: maven, conditional-statements, pom.xml

I have a basic maven question and I can't seem to find the answer that will do the trick.

Basically I would like to make a conditional statement. Similar to the java equivalent:

if(true)
   system.out.println("hello");

What are the possible ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Maven is declarative, not procedural. The only 'conditional' construct is the 'skip' parameter supported by many plugins, and potentially triggered by profile activations.

Your question would need to be far more specific to allow any more specific answer.

Comment: So I have been reading and I feel there is a way to use the ant plugin to do it. However, I am finding numerous different methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`profiles`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to kind of achieve what you want. Using their [`activation`](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html) section a profile (and therefore its content - i.e. plugin definitions) are only turned on "if" a certain situation is true (i.e. a file exists, or a specific property has a certain value etc).

How you would do this depends on your specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are not the only one having the need for simple conditional execution.

[bmargulies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131433/bmargulies) answer shows how in the maven world you might get the answer "we do not understand the need - please be more specific" instead of fulfilling the need in a straight forward manner.

If you switch from maven to [gradle](https://gradle.org/) you'll find a simple if/else construct right in the [tutorial using tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html).

```java
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(release)) {
        version = '1.0'
    } else {
        version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

Comment: the question clearly asks for maven solution, unless you have no idea about the answer. please update your answer with Maven solution